# Can Sundial of the Infinite interrupt multiple-card draws while drawing?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I'm not quite sure about the interaction between the stack and multiple-card draws.

> **120.2.** Cards may only be drawn one at a time. If a player is instructed to draw multiple cards, that player performs that many individual card draws.

According to [Is drawing multiple cards an atomic action?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/21042/is-drawing-multiple-cards-an-atomic-action), this means that:

> *"draw 2 cards" really means "draw a card, then draw a card".* - diego

Now, my question is: Does that mean that a player, affected by a multiple-card draw ([Divination](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=416866) for example), can draw one card and avoid drawing any more by activating [Sundial of the Infinite](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=228118) inbetween individual draws?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No.

In order to activate an ability or cast a spell, a player must have priority. During the resolution of spells and abilities, players do not receive priority.

One advantage of declaring "multiple draws are done one at a time" is multiple card drawing cleanly interacts with cards like [Abundance](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAbundance%5d), [Alhammarret's Archive](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAlhammarret%27s%5d%2b%5bArchive%5d), or cards that say, "[whenever you draw a card](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&text=%20%5B%22whenever%20you%20draw%20a%20card%22%5D)"